# How to react to selection in designer at design time?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, design-time

I built a WPF custom control which derived from `HeaderedItemsControl` and whose items are hidden by default (they become visible when the user clicks the header).

I want to add design time support for this control similar to the `Expander` control. By default, it's content is hidden but when it is selected in the document outline or the designer, its content is shown.

**My actual question is: how can I react to selection in the VS / Blend visual designer to achieve the same behavior as e.g. the `Expander` for my control?**

I learned that there is a `DesignerProperties.DesignMode` attached property that I can use to check whether the control is currently executed in the designer or not. But how can I react to a selection event to make my items visible?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Edit:** I'm targeting Visual Studio / Blend 2013.